# How to access local files in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have been trying to list bunch of files from an ios application on my iPhone 13.
I am completely new to iOS development. Just doing a hobby project.

All I want to do is list all the files in a directory that I created in my iPhone. Here those files don't come with the application. They are the local files stored in phone.

```html
let fileNames = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/Applications")
```

T

Answer (score 0):

If the file/folder isn't owned by the app (isn't under the App's directory) then you simply can't access it. Unless you implement a [Document Picker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller), but then the user must manually select the files that the App will be able to see.

Comment: Thank you so much @marc. I will look into Document picker and try to work things out.